# Relaxed "angularjs" style expression parsing missing in vue

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

If I in vue have an expression like

```
{{foo.earlier_versions.length}}
```

... the page is emitting an error if `foo` or `foo.earlier_versions` is undefined, but angularjs (if I had used that) would be more relaxed and just give us an empty result.

The error I get is like

[image: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')]

and the page execution is terminated.

Is there a way to have vue equally forgiving?

It would really help to not have to write long expressions just to make them "correct".

Comment: please share you whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have all the recent dependencies/ devDependencies you can use this

```html
<span class="ml-5 font-bold">
   {{ foo?.earlier_versions?.length ?? 'fallback value' }}
</span>
```